# Метод и форма POST в условном операторе

Tags: php, form

**Добрый вечер!:)**

Пишу сценарии тестирование на языке PHP. Простым языком без всяких закручек.
А вот незадача, не обрабатывается форма в условном операторе.

```
<?php 
echo ("
    Предлагается пройти тест. Пожалуйста, жмите на кнопку.
    <form method='post'>
        <input method='post'
               name='test'
               id='submitButton'
               type='submit'
               value='Начать'
               class='ver_normal_red_lft'>
        <input method='post'
               name='retest'
               id='submitButton'
               type='submit'
               value='Сброс'
               class='ver_normal_red_lft'>
        ");
$test = $_POST['test'];

if ($test == 'Начать') {
    $start = 1;
}

$retest = $_POST['retest'];

if ($retest == 'Сброс') {
    echo ("<br />Тест успешно сброшено");
}

echo (
    "<br />Значение START: " . $start
    . "<br />Значение TEST: " . $test
    . "<br />Значение RETEST: " . $retest
);

if ($start == 1) {
    echo (
        "<br />Вам уже есть 18 лет?
        <input method='post' name='yes' type='submit' value='Да'>
        <input method='post' name='no' type='submit' value='Нет'>"
    );
    $yes = $_POST['yes'];
    $no = $_POST['no'];
    echo ("<br />Значение YES:" . $yes);
    echo ("<br />Значение NO:" . $no);
}

echo ("<br />Значение YES:" . $yes);
echo ("<br />Значение NO:" . $no);
?>
```

Переменные
`$test` - если пользователь нажмет на кнопку, переменная `$start` присвоит значение 1.
`$retest` - сброс всех функции, пока еще до ума не довел.

В то же время, когда уже нажали на кнопку "Начать", и тут же есть присвоенные переменные `$start`, было указано, что равно 1. Создаю еще условный оператор, при условии, что `$start=1`. И вот здесь в теле условного оператора не присваиваются значения из формы POST.

Или в условном операторе не будет работать формы и методы POST?

Comment: @rapniger, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У вас половина переменных не объявлены в момент вывода.
Как вариант можно сделать так.

```
Предлагается пройти тест. Пожалуйста, жмите на кнопку.
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' name='test' value='Начать' class='ver_normal_red_lft' id='submitButton'>
    <input type='submit' name='retest' value='Сброс' class='ver_normal_red_lft' id='submitButton'>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
            echo "<br>Вам уже есть 18 лет?";
            echo "<input name='18yes' type='submit' value='Да'>";
            echo "<input name='18no' type='submit' value='Нет'>";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['18yes'])) {
            echo "<br />Да, мне есть 18.";
        } elseif (isset($_POST['18no'])) {
            echo "<br />Нет, мне нет 18.";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['retest'])) { 
            echo "<br>Тест успешно сброшено";
            header("Refresh: 1");
        }
    ?>

</form>
```

$_POST - является суперглобальной переменной. https://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.superglobals.php

Дальше, исходя из ваших потребностей, уже делайте что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, так уже проще писать.